# Problem with Dom-event to an array of buttons

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, debugging, dom-events

I am trying to create a visual element where you can add and remove 2 input fields and a p element, while I found a way to do it, While removing them not in chronological order the last div wont be removed and prints me "cant remove of undefied"

I tried doing it in a few ways, through if function, throgh array methods etc... always the same problem

so the Html code goes this way

```
<main id="mainBlock">
        <div class="divBlock">
                <input class="name" type="text">
                <input class="workingHours" type="text">
                <p class="money"></p>
                <button class="deleteButton">delete</button>
        </div>
        <button id="addButton">add</button>     
</main>
```

and the js:

```js
let addButton = document.getElementById('addButton');
let allDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('divBloc');
addButton.onclick = function(){
    let deleteButtons = document.querySelectorAll('button.deleteButton');
    let allDeleteButtonsArr = Array.from(allDeleteButtons)


    allDeleteButtonsArr.forEach(item => {
        item.onclick = function(){
           let indexNumber = allDeleteButtonsArr.indexOf(item);
           allDivs[indexNumber].remove();
        };
    });
```

I think i should explain while the onclick function is related to the create button at first. For the purpose of giving you easier time to read I delete all the part where I create all the new p div and input elements when you click on it. because each time you click on add element there is a new index number I thought it will be better to include it inside the addButton onclick fucntion.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're dynamically appending nodes, and then you wish to remove them, adding/removing event handlers to the delete button might be very annoying.

A better way is to use event delegation by adding the event listener to the container `#mainBlock`, and when it's called check if the the delete button was called, and if so remove it's parent.

```js
const item = `
  <div class="divBlock">
    <input class="name" type="text">
    <input class="workingHours" type="text">
    <p class="money"></p>
    <button class="deleteButton">delete</button>
  </div>
`;

const container = document.querySelector('#mainBlock');
const addButton = document.querySelector('#addButton');

addButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  addButton.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', item);
});

container.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if(!e.target.matches('.deleteButton')) return;
  
  e.target.parentNode.remove();
});
```

```html
<main id="mainBlock">
  <button id="addButton">add</button>
</main>
```